# Badge for elected Moderators

Tags: discussion, election, badges

I think an elected Moderator should have a badge for getting elected.
That way past moderators will be esteemed for their contribution.

Come to think of it - if there are badges for voting[`(Constituent)`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/badges/100/constituent) and even for visiting[`(Caucus)`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/badges/99/caucus),
There really should be a Badge for `Nomination` as well.

**EDIT:**
As @Mat pointed, there is a similiar new [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181668/allow-ex-moderators-to-opt-in-to-having-a-mark-on-their-profile-indicating-they) for a hollow diamond next to ex-moderators names.
I believe we can wait until that request will be denied (it probably will), and then start discussing again :)
As for Nominees, I still think a badge would be nice addition.

Comment: Badges, we don't need no more stinkin' badges.

Comment: yo dawg ... i herd you like badges so we put a badge on your badge so you can badge while you badge

Comment: Are you assuming moderators are elected for a fixed term?

Comment: @JackDouglas Are moderators elected forever? That might be another question to be asked on meta... I think many politicians would love the idea of being democratically elected for good :)

Comment: Most mods are elected like supreme court justices. For as long as they want to be in power, so to speak

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181668/allow-ex-moderators-to-opt-in-to-having-a-mark-on-their-profile-indicating-they (and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169952/is-the-community-moderator-position-permanent)

Comment: Can I have a badge for being lazy?

Comment: @Mat Great reference, I now know and understand the reason why moderators are elected for as long as they are up to it. I also understand that there is a 6-days-old feature-request for a hollow diamond next to ex-mods names...

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO There is already a badge for being [boring](http://dba.stackexchange.com/badges/21/tumbleweed "tumbleweed"), so why not? :)

Comment: @Justicator That requires effort.

Comment: Can I have a badge for not having badges?

Comment: That's like saying there is no absolute truth, which would contradict itself (cause it would have to be true) and therefore cannot be true....

Comment: I think it is worthwhile for the badges. They are something to work for. And I think (to a point) badges help with encouraging and growing community. One of the reasons why I like the SE sites. Perhaps for Nominations though it would have to have the requirement of having received at least one vote? This way we don't have just anyone getting the badge for any old reason.

Comment: @Chris would it still be a contradiction if contradictions also don't exist?

Comment: @JackDouglas - Interesting thought...but if you still walk through the logic, what you are proposing can't be true either, as it falls into the same issue, especially if you place it side by side with the original thought ("there is no absolute truth"). If contradictions don't exist, that would be an absolute truth, which would then negate the above saying again. :)

Comment: @Chris you are a philosopher :)

Comment: So....where we at on this one? Badge or no badge for moderators? Badge or no badge for nominees?

Comment: @ChrisAldrich Thanks for taking it seriously, maybe if there will be a few more upvotes we can make a request out of this, but for now it looks like only the two of us think it will be an encouraging feature...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187951/158667 - [status-completed]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has been discussed on meta.se to great length, and it is not valid. Also hats.